# Making items equally fill a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have tried since yesterday to get this to work. I. Cannot. GET THESE FLEX ITEMS TO FILL THE CONTAINER. I just want them to equally fill the width and height. I plugged in pretty much anything that i could find but I don't know, it doesn't like me.

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Practice Website</title>
<style>
.orange_text {
  color: orange;
  }
p {
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.item {
  display:flex;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 50%;

}
hr {
  border-top: 10px solid orange;
}

</style>
<body>
<header>
<table>
  <td><h1><span class="orange_text">PRACTICE</span>SITE</h1></td>
  <td><p style="display: inline-block; color: gray;">A practice website(:</br>Cool 
<u>Wow</u></td>
</table>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="item" style="background-color: #ff8500;">EXAMPLE</div></td>
        <td><div class="item" style="background-color: #e42a2b;">EXAMPLE</div></td>
        <td><div class="item" style="background-color: #a700fe;">EXAMPLE</div></td>
        <td><div class="item" style="background-color: #4aa7f4;">EXAMPLE</div></td>
        <td><div class="item" style="background-color: #41cf5f;">EXAMPLE</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr>
</header>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.container` div (= flex parent) has only one child (= flex item): the `table`. Remove the opening and closing `table` and `tr` tags and change the `td` s to `div`s, then the flex settings of `.container` will affect those.